# How to view a multicast stream in Silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight, multicast

I have a multicast stream being generated on one of my servers. The url to the stream is http://mystreamer1/VBR-Movies-MulticastDarwin.sdp. I have read that Silverlight supports viewing of multicast streams but I haven't the first clue on how I need to configure the Silverlight control on my site to connect to the stream. For VOD I just set the media element .source to a URL for a video. I tried to set the .source to the stream url but nothing. I have goggled a lot and have not found any examples. Does anyone have some good advice?

I just want to point Silverlight to my multicast server and view. Do I need to deal with all the UdpSingleSourceMulticastClient, BeginJoinGroup, ReceiveFromSource and MediaElement.SetSource?

Anyone out there have experience with Silverlight and multicast?

Thanks!